# How do I represent time as an int in a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time

I have a DataFrame, read in from a CSV, as such (times as HH:MM:SS):

```
    pta         ptd         tpl_num
4   05:17       05:18       0
6   05:29:30    05:30       1
9   05:42       05:44:30    2
11  05:53       05:54       3
12  06:03       06:05:30    4
17  06:24:30    NaN         5
```

`dtypes`:

```
pta                object
ptd                object
tpl_num             int64
```

I'm trying to get the `pta` and `ptd` columns as an `int`, in the format:

```
    pta      ptd      tpl_num
4   51700    51800    0
6   52930    53000    1
9   54200    54430    2
11  55300    55400    3
12  60300    60530    4
17  62430    NaN      5
```

Seems quite simple - pad trailing zeroes, and convert to an int. But I can't find a way to do it. I've converted to string, padded the zeroes, stripped the colons, but that won't allow me to convert to int due to the `NaN` cells not being recognised. I can't convert to `datetime` without having the `:SS` in all cells. Not sure what to do.

Comment: `051700` for `pta` and  `051800` for `ptd` are not numbers, they are strings. their integer equivalents would be  `51700` and `51800` to change them to ints use `astype(int)` or `pd.to_numeric`

Comment: I've tried converting to string, then stripping the colons, then using `astype`, but the NaN's cause an exception.

Comment: you need to fill the `nan` values try `.fillna(0).astype(int)`

Comment: Filling with zeroes ends up representing 12:00AM in terms of time (i.e. 00:00 > 0000 > 0), do you see my issue?

Comment: can you try `df[['pta','ptd']].apply(pd.to_numeric)` this works for me with NaN values.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you could use;

```
final = df.assign(**pd.to_datetime(df[['pta','ptd']].stack()).dt.time.astype(str)
      .str.replace(':','').astype(int).unstack())
```

---

```
        pta      ptd  tpl_num
4   51700.0  51800.0        0
6   52930.0  53000.0        1
9   54200.0  54430.0        2
11  55300.0  55400.0        3
12  60300.0  60530.0        4
17  62430.0      NaN        5
```

Comment: That looks ideal.. what's the double asterisk doing can I ask?

Comment: That is assigning based on python kwarg or keyword argument :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to eventually get to `datetime` objects.

You could make a helper function to convert the raw strings like:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

col = pd.Series(['5:17', '05:30', np.NaN, '12:30:10'])

def date_converter(t):
    if pd.isna(t):
        return t
    if t.count(':')==2:
        return datetime.strptime(t, '%H:%M:%S')
    if t.count(':')==1:
        return datetime.strptime(t, '%H:%M')
    else:
        return None

col_converted = [date_converter(t) for t in col]

print(col_converted)
```

Output:

```
[datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 5, 17), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 5, 30), nan, datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 12, 30, 10)]
```

Comment: No, I'm aiming towards an `int` representation (of just the time) to use with scikit-learn.

Comment: How do you intend to handle the NaN's ?

Comment: OK, do you not then want to covert to common units like minutes or seconds?
For instance, if you convert 12:30 and 1:00 given this schema, you'll get 1230 and 100 even though 1:00 is after 12:30?  I would think you want to convert to common units if you are going to use it as an input vector for training.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an adjustment that converts to decimalized minutes, which should be appropriate for training:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

col = pd.Series(['5:17', '05:30', np.NaN, '12:30:10'])

def to_minutes(t):
    if pd.isna(t):
        return t
    if t.count(':')==2:
        t = [int(s) for s in t.split(':')]
        return 60*t[0] + t[1] + 1.0/60*t[2]
    if t.count(':')==1:
        t = [int(s) for s in t.split(':')]
        return 60*t[0] + t[1] 


col_converted = [to_minutes(t) for t in col]

print(col_converted)
```

Output:

```
[317, 330, nan, 750.1666666666666]
```

Regarding your comment that you just want to convert to an integer for scikit.learn, you MUST convert to a common set of units.  You cannot just slam together converted integers.  If you do, you have changed a *continuous* variable to an *ordinal* variable because you have destroyed the linearity.  Unless you desire *ordinal* variable don't do this.  For example, if we look at 10-minute increments across an hour boundary, you get something like this:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

col = pd.Series(['5:00', '05:10', '5:20', '5:30', '5:40', '5:50', '6:00', '6:10', '6:20', 
    '6:30', '6:40', '6:50'])

def to_minutes(t):
    if pd.isna(t):
        return t
    if t.count(':')==2:
        t = [int(s) for s in t.split(':')]
        return 60*t[0] + t[1] + 1.0/60*t[2]
    if t.count(':')==1:
        t = [int(s) for s in t.split(':')]
        return 60*t[0] + t[1] 

def to_int(t):
    return int(t.replace(':',''))



true_mins = [to_minutes(t) for t in col]

skewed_time = [to_int(t) for t in col]
print(true_mins)
print(skewed_time)


plt.plot(true_mins, skewed_time)
plt.xlabel('actual minutes')
plt.ylabel('bogus time')
plt.show()
```

[image: bogus time vs. actual time]